# Is it possible to copy selected items from Datagrideview to clipbord c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to copy the selected items  in a datagridview to the clipbord, Here is what i have tried.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.SetText(dataGridView1.SelectedRows);
}
```

Comment: You don't have to do this yourself. See [How to: Enable Users to Copy Multiple Cells to the Clipboard from the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/enable-users-to-copy-multiple-cells-to-the-clipboard-datagridview) which shows how to use the [DataGridView.GetClipboardContent Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.getclipboardcontent?view=netcore-3.1) which _Retrieves the formatted values that represent the contents of the selected cells for copying to the Clipboard._

Comment: Note also: _This method combines these values into a DataObject containing several formats for copying to the clipboard. The supported clipboard formats include DataFormats.Text, DataFormats.UnicodeText, DataFormats.Html, and DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can copy it. You either can do it manually or by coding

`Get(this.dataGridViewEmployee, new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(this.dataGridViewEmployee.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, this.dataGridViewEmployee.CurrentRow.Index));`

This is the code that I used for one of my projects. Hope this works with you

Answer (score 1):

From [This Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/enable-users-to-copy-multiple-cells-to-the-clipboard-datagridview) I'm sure you can achieve what it is you want. I'll give you an example and have you do some small changes if you need.

In your `Form_Load` event add this line of code `this.dataGridView1.ClipboardCopyMode =                 DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithoutHeaderText;` This enables users to copy multiple cells.

In your `Button_Click` event you're going to want to add the code below:

```
if (this.dataGridView1
            .GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Add the selection to the clipboard.
                    Clipboard.SetDataObject(
                        this.dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent());

                }
                catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error");
                }
            }
```

That should copy all the selected cells to the clipboard. Again, I got all this code directly from [Microsofts Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/enable-users-to-copy-multiple-cells-to-the-clipboard-datagridview) on how to do this.

Comment: It works for copping the only one sell, I need to copy the whole row or rows when selected.

Comment: I edited my answer to hopefully get what it is you want.